# How is the limit defined on the number of function calls in the stack in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, stack, stack-size

I've been looking recently on a deep stack with 2000 recursive function calls, and was wondering how is the limit defined on the number of function calls in the stack in Java?

Comment: Have you thought about reengineering it to be iterative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit is based on the maximum amount of stack memory that is allocated to each thread. You can configure this limit using the -Xss JVM argument. See these links for more details:

[Hotspot FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#threads_oom)

[Using Xss To Adjust Java Default Thread Stack Size](http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/209/using-xss-to-adjust-java-default-thread-stack-size-to-save-memory-and-prevent-stackoverflowerror/)

Answer (score 1):

As the others say, it depends on the number of memory available to the JVM.

Theoretical you could compute from the memory the number of function calls, **if** (and this is a big if) you know the functions and their memory consumption. As a (unoptimized) recursive function has to place all locals and parameters on the stack this is very dependent on the the function. That means when you got X functions with no locals and one int parameter on the stack you get only X/4 when you got one with 2 int parameters and 2 int local variables (neglecting other stack frame overhead, as exception, return addresses, ...).